# replace div with toggleMe script

Tags: javascript

I have three linked images each with a different id. I also have three divs that are referencing the corresponding image id. I have enabled the toggleMe script in the page and works. My issue is how do I change this script so I do not have to click the link again to collapse/expand the content?  For example... If I click on Image A, I want the content for Image A to expand. Then if I click on Image B, I want the content for Image A to collapse and Image B to expand without having to click on Image A again. Or if I click on Image C I want the previous content to collapse and the new content for Image C to expand.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
  var e=document.getElementById(a);
  if(!e)return true;
  if(e.style.display=="none"){
    e.style.display="block"
  } else {
    e.style.display="none"
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: will you be able to use jquery

Comment: yes, but I would like to try to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: can you share your html also

Comment: <div>
    <div>
       <a onclick="toggleMe('one'); ">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a onclick="toggleMe('two'); ">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a onclick="toggleMe('three'); ">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div id="one">First div of text</div>
    <div id="two">Second div of text</div>
    <div id="three">Third div of text</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is called accordian.  jquery ui has an out-of-the-box implementation of this. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

put this in your head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script> $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
</script>
```

and you content would have this structure:

```
 <div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        First
      </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Second 
      </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Third
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is an example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abell25/NVxa3/)

Comment: This is a nice script, however I need the div content to appear in the same location. For example if I have three image links inline together, then when you click on link 1, below those image links appears another set of links (submenu), click on link 2, that same submenu changes with a different set of links, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
  var allIds = ['one', 'two', 'three']; // store all of involved ids here
  var e=document.getElementById(a);
  if(!e)return true;
  for (var i = 0; i < allIds.length; i++) {
    if (allIds[i] != a) {
      document.getElementById(allIds[i]).style.display="none";
    }
  }
  if(e.style.display=="none") e.style.display="block";
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This helped, however all the content divs show up initially, then when the links are clicked, they disappear. I am unable to get them back by clicking the links again. What I want it for none to show on opening the page, then as you click the links, they switch out with one another, showing only one div content at a time.

Comment: Wait... sorry... I forgot to change the allIds to the Ids that I had. I changed and they are switching out with one another now. It works, however... how do I have no divs show when initially loading the page. Where does the return false; statement go so no divs show until a link is clicked?

Comment: One other thing... for example... If I click on link 1 and then click on link 2 they change like they should. However, if I click on link 2 again... the div disappears. I do not want a div to disappear if they click on it again... just for the div to show again or basically stay put and not change. I hope this makes sense. Basically this is used for a navigation bar that toggles between different menu options so I always want a div to show. Do I need a placeholder div to show initially with nothing in it then allow for the switching between link 1 , link 2, and link 3?

Comment: If you don't want for divs to hide, you need to remove the `} else { e.style.display="none" }` part from your code.

Comment: Can you show the new block of code with this part removed, I am getting an error in dreamweaver when I remove the  } else { e.style.display="none" } from the code. and doesn't work.

Comment: updated the answer - has an extra `}` in my comment above, sorry

Comment: So I removed the code you showed in the example above and now the links will not switch out with one another. It doesn't do anything. Does there not need to be some kind of else statement?

Comment: Try another modification of the answer, I had to take the for loop out of the `if(e.style.display=="none")` statement. hope it works for you.

Comment: Awesome! The onclicks are working great... now 1 more question. :) When the page initially comes up, all three divs are displaying. How do I get the divs not to display until a link is clicked?

Comment: you can whether make those divs `display: none` in css (preferable) or add `window.onload = function () { // your code to make all divs you need display none };` to the top of your javascript.

Comment: Oh my goodness!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH for all your help! It is working beautifully!!!

Comment: Okay so I tried putting my code into jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ydvuN/1/ but not sure if I got it all right, because it is not working like it is on my test site. Basically the script that you helped me with was working great except for one thing... The tabs would not toggle unless I clicked on one tab, then clicked on another tab to "activate" the code. It is kind of hard to explain the outcome, so I was trying to recreate the issue in jsfiddle, but I am obviously missing something it is cause it wont toggle at all. Can you help me again. :)